# How to create a "more details" control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Can you recommend control or maybe an easy way to do this in WPF application. What I want is control that will collapse and expand itself on button press. It will be great if it looks like Win7 default one.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are - [Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx). Use [IsExpanded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.isexpanded.aspx) property to change `Expander`'s content visibility from code, or use built-in toggle button to change it interactively.

[image]

The read area is a header of `Expander`, the green area is a content of `Expander`.
To achieve the same behavior, you also need to set [Expander.ExpandDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.expanddirection.aspx) property to `Up` value.

If you want to animate expanding, you'll need to add a trigger on `IsExpanded = true` an animation storyboard.

Comment: It's not that easy: in this case the expanded part is outside the body of the expander, and it is animated.

Comment: Notice how "From: DATA (D:)" is not inside the expander.

Comment: @Baboon: it's just a header modification - you'll need "From: DATA (D:)" to be visible in the header, when `IsExpanded` is false. Don't invent the wheel.

Comment: And now, the hardest part, notice how this is not animated. Which is why i preferred to offer a solution that has the animation already made and do the header by hand than the other way around. It's not a piece of cake your way!

Comment: it is not just a header modification, that line is in the middle of the content of your expander.

Comment: @Baboon: animation here will be trivial. And the task, in whole, is a trivial task. And you're propagating the solution, that is the inventing of the wheel. The line "From: DATA (D:)" isn't at the middle of content. You need two lines "From: DATA (D:)" - one in the header, one in the content. When the content is expanded, line in the header is collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the framework itself to do precisely that, but it's easy to bend it your way.

You can use the [Reveal](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot/blob/master/net40-client/Bot/Reveal.cs) control (from Bag of Tricks), and plant the toggle button that triggers the animation in the bottom bar.

Just copy/paste the control in your solution, then use it like this:

```
<local:Revealer IsExpanded="{Binding DetailsShown}">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding DetailInfoOne}" />
   ...
</local:Revealer>
```

And then at another location (bottom of your window?)

```
<ToggleButton Content="More details" IsChecked="{Binding DetailsShown}" />
```

Putting the arrow button and changing text to "Fewer details" is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like setting all your detailed info in a stack panel and put it to Visibility of Collapsed. When you push the button, set it to visible. The summary info is then set to collapsed and vice-versa.

The form will have to have a size set to Auto so that it will change depending of the content.

Hope that helps.